# mod_rewrite images in .css stylesheet require absolute path now?

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following mod_rewrite code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#SecFilterInheritance Off
ErrorDocument 404 /fourohfour.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(myurl\.com)$ [NC]   **changed the domain name for this posting **
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /article.php?id=$1&articleTopic=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Problem is when I visit the artcle.php web URL the images referred to in my CSS documents are no longer loading.  That is probably because they require the myurl.com absolute pathway now that I am using mod rewrite

For instance:

```
    background: #D4D9DD url('images/bg03.jpg');
```

needs to be changed to:

```
    background: #D4D9DD url('http://www.myurl.com/images/bg03.jpg');
```

But I have lots of images in many CSS files .

Is there a way I can modify the .htaccess so relative pathways in CSS are kept and I wouldn't have to manually change each image reference in eacy of my CSS files?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best idea to give the server the unnecessary work of rewriting image requests when you don't have to.

Presumably the browser is requesting the images like so:

```
http://www.myurl.com/article/IDNum/ArticleTitle/bg03.jpg
```

So you could still use relative paths they just need to account for the fake directories:

```
background: #D4D9DD url('../../images/bg03.jpg');
```

Just run a mass search and replace, replacing **'images/** with **'../../images/**

The same logic will also work in a mod_rewrite rule but, again, why use processor cycles you don't need to? Hopefully some day your site will be high traffic and you'll thank yourself for keeping things efficient.

Or alternatively:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Side note: search engines really don't care about search engine friendly URLs anymore. Haven't for years.

Comment: skel.min.js is not finding the css files due to the mod_rewrite...firebug says:   http://www.myurl.com/articles/1/css/style.css 404 (Not Found) .. problem is this link is being generated by skel.min.js, not my code but this .js library that I am using... without mod_rewrite skel.min.js and all CSS works fine.. the mod_rewrite is messing it up.  any ideas?

Comment: It's the same situation as the images, try loading skel.min.js with the full URL instead of a relative one, it should then look for style.css in the right place.